Manhwa/manhua where the main character has an identity sign-in system
I read this manhwa/manhua a long time ago and don't remember many details. Here is what I remember:
The main character (MC) has a career/identity change system on Earth, in modern times, and the system gave the MC an identity/career of an alien who is tasked to save his alien world.
That's all I know about the manhwa/manhua I read.
